Future method not getting called in Auth providers
From out external .Net application after user log in by clicking on one card we are redirecting the user to our salesforce community sites.
In order to establish SAML communication under Auth Providers we mapped one APEX class in registration handler and inside that APEX we are calling one future method to assign permission set and that future method is not getting called.
We need this future method as we are doing some operation on both set up and non set up objects.
Execute as user is System Admin profile only and Author Apex permission is there for the user.
The community user coming from .Net application is having CC+ license.
We did lots of trial and error thing only as not sure where the issue is and nothing is working.
Strange thing is other methods inside that APEX are getting called, but only this future method is not getting called.

You are aware a future method is called as a separate transaction, after the current transaction completes? If debugging, are you checking the at-least-two debug logs generated here (one for the call to the auth provider and one for the future method execution)?

Yes. In developer console there is no logs for future handler call. But if we call the same class in Anonymous apex by paasing values to the entry point method then logs are coming for future handler call

Being this is happening during the authentication process, maybe you need to consider who the contextual user would be...? I haven't research that myself so back to you for some investigation. It may be that this uses the Automated Process user?

One another thing is in the future method we are assigning permission set to that CC+ user. If we manually assign that permission set to that CC+ user in SF and if we try the same process from log in to .NET application and switching to SF at that time that future method is getting called. why we are doing this way is from external application we have two card.if the user clicks on one card then we will remove one permission set and assign other permission

Like I said, this is very likely related to the contextual user for the auth provider processing (since this would also apply to the future method). It is always possible, because of this happening before authentication is complete, that SF does not support initiating async processing. Have you done some research around this?

Not getting this. Actually registration handler execute user is under system admin profile. But if we assign permission set to the CC+ user then future method is calling. So not sure under which user I need to look into? . Can you give some insigths I will look into that way

OK, so I took a look at the docs and see that the registration handler runs under a user you specify. You should therefore enable debug for that user and look for the multiple logs that will be generated.

I checked the logs wven by making the level as Finer but not able to see any exception or any different thing. Kind of strange

Thanks @PhilW for trying to solve this. Since I was not able to find the root cause I took different approach to resolve the issue. In the registration hadler , now I am just updating the user record and Assigning permission set only. Wrote a trigger on user object and in that trigger called a future method and inside that method I am updating contact and Account. This work around worked for me. Once again thanks. May be I need to raise a case with salesforce for the above all issues.

Just be aware of the constraints and limitations around using a future method from a trigger - when there is bulk DML or when there are DMLs in a future method context, it will fail.

Thanks @PhilW. Will take those into consideration

Read up on an alternative here.
